# parseInt returns NaN when it should be a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan, custom-data-attribute, parseint

I have the following code:

```js
$(function() {
    var $form = $("#pollAnswers"),
        $radioOptions = $form.find("input[type='radio']"),
        $existingDataWrapper = $(".web-app-item-data"),
        $webAppItemName = $existingDataWrapper.data("item-name"),
        $formButton = $form.find("button");
    
        $radioOptions.on("change",function(){
    
          $formButton.removeAttr("disabled");
    
          var chosenField = $(this).data("field"), 
              answer_1 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-1")),
              answer_2 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-2")),
              answer_3 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-3"));
            
            console.log("1 =" + answer_1);
            console.log("2 =" + answer_2);
            console.log("3 =" + answer_3);
            
            //Additional code not related to question
         });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="web-app-item-data" data-item-name="Test" data-answer-1="0"  data-answer-2="0"  data-answer-3="0"></div>

<form id="pollAnswers">
    <div class="answers">
        <input type="radio" name="radioChoice" data-field="CAT_Custom_2"> Answer 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioChoice" data-field="CAT_Custom_4"> Answer 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioChoice" data-field="CAT_Custom_6"> Answer 3<br>
    </div>
<button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

When you run the code you will see in your console that Answers 1, 2 and 3 all return `NaN`.

**Update**:

As Charlie H pointed out in a comment, if I remove `parseInt` it returns `undefined`.

I don't see the error in the code for why it isn't pulling the data attribute values from the div.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What does *existingDataWrapper.data("answer-1")* gives you without parseInt

Comment: @CharlieH - `undefined` is what it gives me. Is there something incorrect with the jQuery pulling the data attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jQuery 2.1.3** does not appear to recognize data- attributes that contain a name-segment that consists only of numbers. For instance, these work:

- `data-answer` as `.data()["answer"]`
- `data-foo` as `.data()["foo"]`
- `data-foo-bar` as `.data()["fooBar"]`

These do not:

- data-answer-1
- data-foo-bar-3

**jQuery 3** appear to behave more as expected.

Comment: Does it? In my testing, it ignores that one completely. Strangely, it DOES allow data-1-answer, however.

Comment: Ah ha! It depends on which version of jQuery you use.

Comment: Good find about the version of jQuery! Another workaround I just realized as you were pointing out what works and doesn't work is to use `data-answer1`. In other words, just remove the `-` and it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The data function from jquery does not seem to be taking attributes into account which have a number in the attribute name. "number-1" is not working but "number-one" does. This might help you as a quick fix.

```js
$(function() {
    var $form = $("#pollAnswers"),
        $radioOptions = $form.find("input[type='radio']"),
        $existingDataWrapper = $(".web-app-item-data"),
        $webAppItemName = $existingDataWrapper.data("item-name"),
        $formButton = $form.find("button");
    
        $radioOptions.on("change",function(){
    
          $formButton.removeAttr("disabled");
    
          var chosenField = $(this).data("field"), 
              answer_1 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-one")),
              answer_2 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-two")),
              answer_3 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-three"));
            console.log("1 =" + answer_1);
            console.log("2 =" + answer_2);
            console.log("3 =" + answer_3);
            
            //Additional code not related to question
         });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="web-app-item-data" data-item-name="Test" data-answer-one="0"  data-answer-two="0"  data-answer-three="0"></div>

<form id="pollAnswers">
    <div class="answers">
        <input type="radio" name="radioChoice" data-field="CAT_Custom_2"> Answer 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioChoice" data-field="CAT_Custom_4"> Answer 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioChoice" data-field="CAT_Custom_6"> Answer 3<br>
    </div>
<button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Before **jQuery 3.0.0**, jQuery attempts to retrieve the rest of the `data-` attribute as camelCase. In other words:

`data-answer-1` becomes camelized to `data-answer1` and attempts to retrieve said attribute (because it fails to normalize it back to `data-answer-1`), which of course there isn't so it returns undefined. Any `data-` attributes that hold more than one dash and aren't camelized properly won't be obtainable through the jQuery `data` methods as they become camelized before actually being retrieved. This includes `data-` attributes that don't start with a letter after the second dash.

Basically, jQuery does:

```
var key = jQuery.camelCase(key);
//... some time later
var attrName = "data-" + key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();
// back to normal or is it...?
elem.getAttribute(attrName); //might not exist.
```

This is already fixed on version 3.0.0 as per this [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2257). Here's the [commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/0e790985a76fd813a6e56696c87abeed5a6cf63b) that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the info! It seems to work in the 1.xx branch, just not 2.xx. Glad to see it is fixed in jQuery 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Jquery allows only one `"-"` in data attributes in versions higher than 1. Your code works very well for all JQuery 1.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can read an attribute using the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function. However, as others have suggested, jQuery doesn't read attribute names with numbers in them.

See the code for solution.

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $("#pollAnswers"),
        $radioOptions = $form.find("input[type='radio']"),
        $existingDataWrapper = $(".web-app-item-data"),
        $webAppItemName = $existingDataWrapper.data("item-name"),
        $formButton = $form.find("button");

        $radioOptions.on("change",function(){

          $formButton.removeAttr("disabled");

          var chosenField = $(this).data("field"), 
              answer_1 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.attr("data-answer-1")),
              answer_2 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.attr("data-answer-2")),
              answer_3 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.attr("data-answer-3"));

            console.log("1 =" + answer_1);
            console.log("2 =" + answer_2);
            console.log("3 =" + answer_3);

            //Additional code not related to question
         });
});
```